# Retrieve some of items in listview virtualmode

Tags: vb.net

I am using a `ListView` with `VirtualMode` enabled.

Using this sub to retrieve items from list(of listviewitem)

```
Dim Customers AS New Lits(of ListViewItem)
Dim Customers_Searched AS New Lits(of ListViewItem)  

Private Sub CustomersList_RetrieveVirtualItem(sender As Object, e As RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs) Handles CustomersList.RetrieveVirtualItem

     If searchbox.text <> "" Then 
         e.Item = Customers_Searched(e.ItemIndex)
     Else
         e.Item = Customers(e.ItemIndex)
     End If

End Sub
```

Everything works fine.

**What I want:** I don't want to have the other `Customers_Searched` list because a lot of time I need to update some items inside the `Customers` list and I don't want to update it twice in `Customers_Searched` list

I want `CustomersList_RetrieveVirtualItem` to retrieve only the matched items to `seachedbox.text` and still have the full list of `Customers`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that if I update an item inside the first list it updated in the other list because the item still itself

I don't know why some users vote this post down
thank you anyway